# Application "Xcode6-beta6" cant be opened -1712

Tags: xcode

I'm having problem launching xcode 6 beta 6 which got installed successfully!. I already have `beta2, beta3, beta4` in my `Application` folder which all are working fine. But when i launch beta6 i get below error. I tried re-installing it re-started the system many times but dint do any favour. Is earlier version's are causing the problem. Anyone encountered similar problem ? please suggest the solution.

[image]

iMac version

[image]

Comment: Are you using Yosemite DP 6 or 7 ?

Comment: You should ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com as -1712 is a common OSX error.  However use `Disk Utility` to correct disk permissions.

Comment: Try Xcode 6 beta 7 released today.

Answer (score 0):

Goto System Preferences -> Security -> General Tab. Under "Allow apps from downloaded from:" select "Anywhere". This did the trick for me while I was trying to install Xcode 6.1.